# Is there anyway I can change the website from ging from .co.uk to .com in the web.config file

Tags: wordpress, web, config, iis-7.5

I have put in this http redirectin the web config file but I keep getting a redirection loop. The website is a wordpress website and is being hosted on IIS7.5, it may also be worth metioning that I have a plug in called really simple ssl installed to handle the https redirects.

I will attach my web.config file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
<rewrite>
  <rules><rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true"><match url=".*" /> 
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
  matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
  matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /></conditions><action 
 type="Rewrite" url="index.php" /></rule>
        <rule name="WordPress: http://www.google.com" 
 patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule></rules>
</rewrite>
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.google.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <denyUrlSequences>
                <add sequence="xmlrpc.php" />
            </denyUrlSequences>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  <handlers>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: could you please explain what is your exact requirement by using some example like . if you enter your iis site url http://www.example.co.uk than it redirects to http://www.example.com

Comment: @JalpaPanchal if you enter .co.uk then it should redirect to .com

Comment: You could use url rewrite rule to redirect url from co.uk to com: `<rule name="Redirect From co to com" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?sample1.(co.uk)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample1.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I've just tried that and there are no redirects happening from .co.uk to .com here is the web config file have i missed something out?

Comment: You could check my result. [image link](https://i.postimg.cc/nVGbx18X/co.jpg)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal https://postimg.cc/YjRQ7Dyn

Comment: in url rewrite rule replace sample1 to with the hostname of your site.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal that returns a 500 internal server error

Comment: could you share your site binding detail? and run failed request tracing to get error detail.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal here are the bindings im just running failed request tracing now
https://postimg.cc/rDVrP1J6

Comment: your site doesn't have any binding with co.uk than how you want to redirect URL like co.uk to .com?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I've created a .co.uk binding and im still getting a 500 error im currently running failed request tracing